# How do I assign an IP address a specific url for ssh?

Tags: ssh, networking, ip

My question my sound unclear so let me rephrase with an example.

When I try to ssh to my school, the format is as follows:

```
ssh <student_id>@<school>.com
```

From school, when I try to ssh home, the format is as follows:

```
ssh <computer_user_name>@<ip_address>
```

When I connect home I'm connecting with an **ip address** but when I connect to school, the **school.com** already corresponds to an IP, so I can just use school.com instead.

How do I get this "alias" for an IP so I can use that instead of writing my full IP out every time?

Answer (score 6):

Use your SSH configuration file at `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host home
    User yourusername
    HostName 10.11.12.13
```

Use your actual IP address.  Be aware that most residential IP addresses are dynamic and subject to change, so you might want to use a DNS service like no-ip.org or dyndns.org to give yourself a domain name you can use in place of the IP address.

Comment: You could also set it in your /etc/hosts file like this:  `10.11.12.13     HostName` . However I would only set it there if you are going to use that name mapping for more than just ssh.  If you only need to map the IP for ssh the ssh config file is a better spot for it as your machine will parse the /etc/hosts file every time it does a name lookup and adding too much in there could add some latency to name resolutions.

Comment: Also, the SSH config file supports wildcards, so you can do things like set your username for any host that matches `*.yourschool.example.com`.

Comment: Okay so suppose I am bob@bob-ubuntu

Then would my file be as follows:

Host home
    bob bob-ubuntu
    ARandomName 10.11.12.13

Comment: If this is the case though, how do I know there isn't another bob@bob-ubuntu in the world, and so when I try to ssh, what if I connect to to them?

Answer (score 0):

The "alias" you mention is a name for your machine, i.e. a host name. These "aliases" are managed globally by a network of domain name (DNS) servers that translate the names into IP addresses. In addition, locally in your machine, there is a file where you can define additional names that will not be available for other machines.

Then, you have two options:

1) **If you want to define the "alias" (hostname) for all the users/machines in the Internet,** you must

- buy a domain name (e.g. `k-split-x.com`) and define the name or the names in a DNS server (e.g. `home.k-split-x.com` and `other.k-split-x.com`), or
- use some service of dynamic DNS with a generic domain. For instance, [Now-Dns](https://now-dns.com/) offers names with the `myiphost.com` domain name.

If you are interested in a dynamic DNS solution, there are some free. You may use Google to find one. [Now-Dns](https://now-dns.com/), [NoIp](https://www.noip.com/) and [FreeDNS](https://freedns.afraid.org/) are some of them.

2) **if you want to define the "alias" only for your machine,** you must modify the "hosts" file.

- In Windows, the hosts file is in `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`
- In Unix, the file is in `/etc/hosts`
- In Mac, it is in `/private/etc/hosts`

You may check information about how to change the file in many websites. I found an explanation in the [Rackspace website](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a domain name in /etc/hosts file
The format is

```
<home IP>  myhome.net
```

I always do that to save my time.